# EntityQuery condition only if field exists

Tags: 8, entities

How to apply a condition only if a field exists?

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'videos')
  ->condition('field_tags', 39, '=')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_date_start', $now->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT), '<=')
  ->condition('field_date_end', $now->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT), '>=')
  ->execute();
```

I want to get nodes that meet the condition about `field_date_end` but also those, that do not have a value for `field_date_end`.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$group = $query
  ->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition('field_date_end', $now->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT), '<=')
  ->notExists('field_date_end');
$results = $query
  ->condition('type', 'videos')
  ->condition('field_tags', 39, '=')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition($group)
  ->execute();
```